# How can I remove my bathroom extractor fan's cover?

Tags: bathroom, fans

I have this Cata B-Plus extractor fan in my bathroom:

[image: extractor fan]

It's connected to the light switch and it stopped working. I want to take the cover off and remove all the dust. If I yank on the cover I can see that it is separating from the unit inside the wall but I can't get it off. What's the trick to getting this thing off? It's on the wall not the ceiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull it outward about 1" (2-3cm). There will likely be a long V-spring on each of two opposing sides that you'll need to disengage from some slots, often by squeezing the legs together.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it. I took the cover off add gave the fan a little nudge.

Comment: Good deal. While you're in there, clean all the gunk off the blades. They get so crudded up that they resemble chicken drumsticks more than a fan.